# How to convert (lat, lon) coordinates to coordinates of tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, latitude-longitude, tkinter-canvas

I have a little question related with converting real coordinates to tkinter canvas coordinates.

**What I have**

I have lists with pairs of coordinates: `[(lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2), (lat3, lon3), ...]`, every pair of every list is creating a line (street with its name etc). So all of lat lon look like this coord: `72.9957321`. If I plot them using matplotlib it will be : [image: picture 1]

**What I want to do**

But I want to display them using tkinter canvas for user to be able to click on the particular street (line on the canvas) and it will return the name of the street. I want picture on this canvas be the as same as matplotlib draw it.

**My problem is**

I do not know how to "convert" lat lon coords to tkinter canvas coords to display roads in a right way on it.

I had an "idea of converting" by simply removing `,` from lat lon coordinates and draw tkinter canvas lines, but the size of the canvas will be enourmous \ improbably big. Maybe possible to change 0 0 coordinates of the canvas to min lat lon coordinates (with removed ,) and set some max coords to restrict user to be over particular area on the canvas.
[image: picture 2]

So its size will not be so large as starting with 0 0 and drawing lines at 53000000 ..., but I think it still isn't a good way to solve the problem.

**Any idea how could I draw roads on tkinter canvas using real lat lons?**

Thank you.

Comment: Relevant, but without answer: [convert-canvas-mouse-coords-to-geographic-coords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948674/convert-canvas-mouse-coords-to-geographic-coords)

Comment: Although technically lat and lon are angular measurements, you may be able to ignore that and just [linearly interpolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) each of them into the corresponding `Canvas` x and y values.

Comment: Find out the minimum and maximum values of `lat` and `lon` and then it is easy to convert those coordinates to canvas coordinates: `x = (lon - lon_min) * width / (lon_max - lon_min)` and `y = lat_max - (lat - lat_min) * height / (lat_max - lat_min)` where `width` and `height` are the size of canvas.